# Weird reaction behavior, ticket system discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, ticket-system

I am trying to make an own ticket system for my discord server with my discord.js bot.
If a user reacts to a certain message with the  emoji, I want it first to delete the reaction instantly, and then continue. So basically the reaction count stays at 1 (the only one from my bot).
The problem is, if I restart the bot and react to the message, it doesn't delete my reaction, however when I manually delete it, and try again, it works!

Here is my code:

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (messageReaction, user) => {
    if (messageReaction.partial) {
        try {
            await messageReaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("couldn't fetch message1", error);
        }
    }
    let msg = messageReaction.message;
    if (msg.id === config.support_msg_id) {
        const userReactions = msg.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(user.id));
        try {
            for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
                await reaction.users.remove(user.id);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Failed to remove reactions.');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `messageReactionAdd` event is only triggered when a reaction is added to a **cached** message, as stated by the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd):

> Emitted whenever a reaction is added to a cached message.

You could fix this by adding every message to the cache when the bot starts by using the following code:

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  client.guilds.cache.each(guild => {
    guild.channels.cache.each(channel => {
      if (channel.type === 'text' || channel.type === 'dm') {
        channel.messages.fetch();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

If you want to prevent too many messages being added to the cache, you can pass [`ChannelLogsQueryOptions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelLogsQueryOptions) to the [`MessageManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) function.

Comment: How does it impact on memory?

Comment: @Cursed I have not tried it, so I'm not entirely sure how much memory it will use up.

Comment: Imagine fetching all the messages on some big bot with 100+ dms and servers

Comment: @Cursed Well, that could cause issues, but we'll never know unless someone tries it.

Comment: sorry for a late answer, I somehow lost the question. I am already  fetching any message coming in in my event. So it should go to the cache anyway shouldn't it? So why doesn't it then work

Comment: @grafpatron I'm not sure. Have you tried the answer to see if it works?